# Remove consumer group created from java spring Kafka listener

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring kafka listener to read messages from kafka topic.

```
@KafkaListener( id = "member-group", topics = "member-updated" )
```

I used to create a new consumer group each time(by changing above group id) to consume all records.
Now I've around 50 consumer group and I want to delete them. I tried to delete from kafka windows client -

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --zookeeper <zookeeper-url> --delete --group <group-name>
```

but it failed with following output -

```
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).
Error: Delete for group '<group-name>' failed because group does not exist.
```

So is there any way to delete these consumer group either by code or by some other tool.
And what is default retention policy for consumer group.

Comment: what version of kafka?

Comment: @Natalia apache kafka client 1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--bootstrap-server host:port` instead of `--zookeeper`.

Run the script without any parameters to get help...

```
--bootstrap-server <String: server to   REQUIRED (for consumer groups based on 
  connect to>                             the new consumer): The server to     
                                          connect to.                          
...
--zookeeper <String: urls>              REQUIRED (for consumer groups based on 
                                          the old consumer): The connection    
                                          string for the zookeeper connection  
                                          in the form host:port. Multiple URLS 
                                          can be given to allow fail-over.
```